# Unable to resolve service for type 'Api.Repositories.UnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'Api.ServicesBusiness.EquipoServices'

Tags: repository-pattern, asp.net-core-webapi, unit-of-work, ef-core-2.2, unitofworkapplication

I want to make a webapi and I'm trying to do it through the services way, I have a repository generic and another 2 repository and a unit of work, apparently everything goes fine, but when I run and test the webapi from postman I got that error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Api.Repository.Repositories.UnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'Api.ServicesBusiness.Implementacion.EquipoServices'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, bool throwIfCallSiteNotFound)

Here is the my dbcontect:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext()
        {
        }
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> option)  :base(option)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Equipo> Equipos { get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\Express;Database=SoftballLeague;Trusted_Connection=True");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the interface of my generic repository:

```
 public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        Task<T> AddAsyn(T t);
        Task<T> UpdateAsyn(T t, object key);
    }
```

Here is the implementation of my generic repository:

```
 public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
        private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _dbSet = _context.Set<T>();
        }

        public virtual async Task<T> AddAsyn(T t)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(t);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return t;

        }

        public virtual async Task<T> UpdateAsyn(T t, object key)
        {
            if (t == null)
                return null;
            T exist = await _dbSet.FindAsync(key);
            if (exist != null)
            {
                _context.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(t);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return exist;
        }
}
```

Here is the interface of my equipo repository:

```
public interface IEquipoRepository:IGenericRepository<Team>
    {
        int GetAverageTeam(string name);
        int GetTeamHit(string name);
}
```

Here is the implementation of my equipo repository:

```
 public class EquipoRepository : GenericRepository<Team>, IEquipoRepository
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext dbContext;
        public EquipoRepository(AppDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
            this.dbContext = context;
        }
        
        public int GetAverageTeam(string name)
        {
            int teamAverage = 0;

            var resultAverage = this.dbContext.Equipos
                           //.SelectMany(bItem => bItem.)
                          .Where(equipo=>equipo.Nombre==name)
                          .SelectMany(equipo => equipo.jugadores)
                          .Average(jugador => jugador.Average);

            if (resultAverage.HasValue)
                teamAverage =Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(resultAverage.Value));

            return teamAverage;
        }

        public int GetTeamHit(string name)
        {
            int resultTotal = 0;

            var result = this.dbContext.Equipos
                          //.SelectMany(bItem => bItem.)
                          .Where(equipo => equipo.Nombre == name)
                          .SelectMany(equipo => equipo.jugadores)
                          .Sum(jugador => jugador.Cant_Hits_Conectados);

            if (result.HasValue)
                resultTotal = result.Value;

            return resultTotal;
        }

}
```

Here is the interface of my unit of work:

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork:IDisposable
    {
        Task Commit();
    }
```

Here is the implementation of my unit of work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _DbContext;

        private EquipoRepository equipoRepository ; 
       
        public UnitOfWork(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this._DbContext = dbContext;
            this.equipoRepository = new EquipoRepository(this._DbContext);
        }

        public EquipoRepository GetEquipoRepository{
            get {
                    if(this.equipoRepository==null)
                        this.equipoRepository= new EquipoRepository(this._DbContext);
                return this.equipoRepository;
            }
                
        }

        public async Task Commit()
        {
            await this._DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this._DbContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Here is the implementation of services interfaces IEquipoServices:

```
 public interface IEquipoServices
    {
        ICollection<EstadisticaEquipoModel>AveragePorEquipo(string name);
        
       int Total2bleConectados(string name);
}
```

Here is the implementation of services EquipoServices which is the one who throws the error:

```
public class EquipoServices : IEquipoServices
    {
        private readonly UnitOfWork unit;

        public EquipoServices(UnitOfWork unitOfWorkFactory)
        {
            this.unit = unitOfWorkFactory;
        }
        public ICollection<EstadisticaEquipoModel> AveragePorEquipo(string name)
        {
            var equipoAverage= this.unit.GetEquipoRepository.GetAverageEquipo(name);
            return equipoAverage;
        }

        public int AveragePorEquipo(string name)
        {
            var result = this.unit.GetEquipoRepository.GetEquipoTotal2bleConectados(name);
            return result;
        }
}
```

This is the controller, here I am just running the ListadoEquipos() method:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class EquipoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IEquipoServices equipoService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public EquipoController(IEquipoServices eqService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.equipoService = eqService;
            this._mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpGet("list")]
        public IEnumerable<string> ListadoEquipos()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
}
```

This is the configuration in the startup.cs file:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
            services.AddSingleton<IEquipoServices, EquipoServices>();
            //services.AddScoped<IJu, JugadorService>();

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You registered `IUnitOfWork`, but you're injecting `UnitOfWork`. The service collection doesn't know how to inject `UnitOfWork` directly.

Long and short, inject `IUnitOfWork` instead:

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork unit;

public EquipoServices(IUnitOfWork unitOfWorkFactory)
```

Comment: if I do that then I can not use in method of EquipoServices eje:
public int GetAverageEquipo(string nombreEquipo)
        {
            var equipoAverage = this.unit.GetEquipoRepository.GetAverageEquipo(name);
            return equipoAverage;
        }

Comment: Then you need to register `UnitOfWork` directly: `services.AddTransient<UnitOfWork>` without the interface. However, you're defeating the entire purpose of using an interface here. You should be able to substitute *any* implementation, so relying on a method only available on a particular implementation is a violation of the liskov substitution principle.

Comment: I want it be available in any services or any repository, I dont know then how to dont defeating the purpose of the interface then, is here a way how I can create a repository without defeating the interfacec?

Comment: Alternatively, you can just get rid of this entire over-engineered mess. `DbContext` is your unit of work, and each `DbSet` is a repository. Using an ORM like EF is opting to use a third-party DAL, instead of creating your own. Creating your own DAL around that is completely pointless, and only adds to the entropy of your code. It's a waste of time, serves no valid purpose, and just adds more things to test, more things to maintain, and more points of failure.